# SWIG CYGWIN DLL linking

Tags: java, gcc, java-native-interface, cygwin, swig

I'm trying to follow the SWIG Java example located [here](http://swig.org/tutorial.html). This example uses cygwin for compilation. I would like to pass the compiler an alredy compiled dll, test.dll, instead of a C source file.  The SWIG.org example uses C source.  I attempted to pass the test.dll(compiled C source) and then example.dll to the 3rd command but I get an error "test.dll: no such file or directory". The SWIG.org example's 3rd command creates the example.dll based on example.c.  How can I create example.dll so that it uses test.dll instead of example.c?

Is there a way to accomplish this within the context of this example?

**My Attempt without C Source, just dll:**

> $ swig -java example.i
>
> $ gcc example_wrap.c -I/c/jdk1.6.0_30/include -I/c/jdk1.6.0_30/include/win32
>
> $ gcc -shared example_wrap.o -mno-cygwin -Wl,--add-stdcall-alias  -o test.dll example.dll

**SWIG.org Example Code:**

```
$ swig -java example.i
$ gcc **-c example.c** example_wrap.c -I/c/jdk1.3.1/include -I/c/jdk1.3.1/include/win32
$ gcc -shared example.o  example_wrap.o -mno-cygwin -Wl,--add-stdcall-alias  -o example.dll
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to use Java 1.3.1 given its almost 12 years old?

Comment: I'm using 1.6, that was from the example...fixed the typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass `test.dll` to the last command, which links your program, rather than the second, which just compiles the example_wrap.c source file. (The `-c` option tells gcc to compile only.)

Note that the ordering of objects and DLLs on the link line is important. DLLs should come after anything that uses them.

Comment: I tried $ gcc -shared example_wrap.o -mno-cygwin -Wl,--add-stdcall-alias -o test.dll example.dll where test.dll is an anlready complied dll of my C libraries and example.dll is a new dll that communicates with it.  I got a gcc: test.dll: No such file or directory.  It should create the test.dll not want it as input, any ideas?